# Exception in thread java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I'm a newbie who is trying to complete the below tutorial

```
    // Create a method called countEvens
    // Return the number of even ints in the given array. 
    // Note: the % "mod" operator computes the remainder, e.g. 5 % 2 is 1. 
/*
 * SAMPLE OUTPUT:
 *  
 * 3
 * 0
 * 2
 *  
 */
```

Below is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a[] = {2, 1, 2, 3, 4};
         countEvens(a); // -> 3
         int b[] = {2, 2, 0};
         countEvens(b); // -> 3
         int c[] = { 1, 3, 5};
         countEvens(c); // -> 0

    }


    public static void countEvens(int[] x){
        int i = 1;
        int count = 0;
        while ( i <= x.length){
            if (x[i] % 2 == 0){
                count ++;
            }
            i ++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
```

The code can be run, but I get the below error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at apollo.exercises.ch05_conditionals.Ex5_CountEvens.countEvens(Ex5_CountEvens.java:23)
    at apollo.exercises.ch05_conditionals.Ex5_CountEvens.main(Ex5_CountEvens.java:10)
```

May I know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `while ( i <= x.length)`, you're looping until `i` is *equal* to the length of `x`. The last index of an array is always *length - 1*, so change the less-than-or-equals (`<=`) to just less-than (`<`). Also, initialize `i` to `0`, as Java arrays are zero-based.

Comment: the problem isn't iterating over the array too many times, it is that arrays are zero based and the OP assumes 1 based

Comment: It is, actually. Covering it up with `i - 1` is a poor solution.

Comment: it isn't, actually. The OP iterates 5 times, but 1~5 rather than 0~4. Not TOO MANY times, but in the wrong position. I agree that i-1 isn't pretty, but it is the quickest solution. BUT you're right. Starting at 0 and iterating to i < x.length is the best solution, mentioned in my post...

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
while ( i <= x.length)
```

should be

```
while ( i < x.length)
```

If the `length` of `x`is 5, for example, the indices are 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. The index goes from 0 up to one less than the length of the array.

However the tidiest way to do this is to use a for each loop rather than a while loop:

```
public static void countEvens(int[] x) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int number : x)
        if (number % 2 == 0)
            count++;
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**'i' should go from 0 to length()-1**, because array indices start at 0, and the index of the last element is length()-1.

Therefore, a correct version of your code would be:

```
public static void countEvens(int[] x){
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while ( i < x.length){
        if (x[i] % 2 == 0){
            count ++;
        }
        i ++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

For your specific purpose, **a for loop would be simpler.**

```
for(int i = 0; i< x.length(); i++){
  if(x[i]%2==0){
  count++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java (and most other languages) are **indexed** starting at 0. However the **length** of an array is the count of the elements in the array. So for your array a[]

```
int a[] = {2,1,2,3,4};
```

The index goes up to 4, whereas the length is 5.

You are getting an index out of bounds error because you are iterating through the array from 1~5 because of the `<=` (less than equal to) operator, but the indices of the array are 0~4. When you access each element of the array you should use

```
if (x[i-1] % 2 == 0) //iterates from 0~4 rather than 1~5
```

otherwise you can set the iterator `int i = 0;` and use the less than `<` operator to ensure the iterator moves 0~4